# Creating a Liquidity Pool Token

Tags: solidity

I am looking to create a yield farming token, and was looking through some code, and noticed that the MasterChef contract (holding the liquidity pool logic) require manual 'adding' of a LP token to the list of pools tied to the MasterChef contract. I was wondering how I can go about creating a LP token, and deploying it to the testnet? So far, I have deployed the native token to the testnet, and also deployed the MasterChef contract to the testnet, but I am not too sure how to create an LP token and add it to the list of pools.

How do I create an LP token and how does it work? Thank you all! Sorry im new to all these blockchain stuff, so if theres any resources that you guys could point me to regarding yield farms and how they work behind the scenes, that would be great too! Thank you